# Extracting initialization of data out the component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Not sure if I am over complicating the code but I was wondering if there is a way to extract initialization of the `items` array outside of the `Header` component and still be able to pass `sessionData`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { Menu } from "antd";
import type { MenuProps } from "antd";
import { UserOutlined, UserAddOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const Header: React.FC = () => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState("register");
  const { data: sessionData, status } = useSession();

  const items: MenuProps["items"] = [
    {
      label: (
        <div className="float-right">
          <Link href="/register">Register</Link>
        </div>
      ),
      key: "register",
      icon: <UserAddOutlined />,
    },
    {
      label: (
        <button
          className="rounded-full bg-white/10 px-10 py-3 font-semibold text-white no-underline transition hover:bg-white/20"
          onClick={sessionData ? () => void signOut() : () => void signIn()}
        >
          {sessionData ? "Sign out" : "Sign in"}
        </button>
      ),
      key: "login",
      icon: <UserOutlined />,
    },
  ];

  const onClick: MenuProps["onClick"] = (e) => {
    setCurrent(e.key);
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center">
      <Menu
        onClick={onClick}
        selectedKeys={[current]}
        mode="horizontal"
        items={items}
        className="mr-4 flex-shrink-0"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: Just an opinion, but I would just inline `items` and `onClick` right into the props and not use these intermediate variables at all. You are just making this harder for yourself.

Comment: That said, you could just make a function that accepts the session data as an argument, and returns the items. Like `const menuItems = getMenuItems(sessionData)`, though I still don't think that's very helpful.

Comment: @AlexWayne I was thinking that it is a good practice to extract initialization of the data out of the component to make it more reusable.

Comment: Could `Header` ever have menu items from a different source? If it can, then initializing them here isn't right all. If not, then this isn't really initialization, it's just the content of the component.

Comment: @AlexWayne as long as it is not coming from a diffrent source it belongs inside the component. Thank you Alex!

Comment: Do you want me to write up the `const menuItems = getMenuItems(sessionData)` as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By parameters in a function:

```
function getMenuItems(sessionData: TypeOfSessionDataHere): MenuProps["items"] {
  return [
    // create items here
  ]
}
```

---

Although, I question the value of this refactor. Your component is very simple, and the items are the actual content that matters here. Putting this in a different file or function, and requiring you use intermediate types seems cumborsome.

I'd just make that inline.

```
      <Menu
        items={[
          //... just inline content here
        ]}
      />
```

---

Or you could make a component for each item if you feel that's cumbersome:

```
      <Menu
        items={[
          {
            label: <RegisterLabel sessionData={sessionData} />,
            key: "register",
            icon: <UserAddOutlined />,
          }, {
            label: <LoginLabel sessionData={sessionData} />,
            key: "login",
            icon: <UserOutlined />,
          }
        ]}
      />
```

---

Lots of choices here.